# How to use Cloudinary file uploader instead of the file system in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

I was working on a project where I had to upload images, so I did that with the NodeJs file system so when a user selects an image and submits the form that image with userId and PostId could save in the hardDrive.
so now when I deployed the application and it doesn't work because there might be thousands of users and for this, I thought about Cloudinary, so now I need to know how to do this part with cloudinary because I am a bit new to nodejs and I wrote some code to handle the image uploader something like this.

and this is the function to save uploaded files into the PC.

and this is another function that handles where should go which file, which means every single image most safe in a different folder with userId.

i really appreciate your suggestion, thanks

## Upate 1

```
    exports.writeFileToFolder = async (file, res, postId) => {
  const filePath =  `/imageUpload/${postId}/${file.name}`;
  console.log("Testing the file uploader in access file", postId);

  try {
    const uploadRersponse = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(filePath, {
      upload_preset: "ml_default"
    })
    console.log("the uploadRersponse", uploadRersponse);
    res.json({ msg: "Uploaded" });

  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: "something has gone wrong!" });
    console.log(error);
  }

};
```

Comment: As you're using Node and want to upload to Cloudinary directly without storing the file locally you may want to checkout Multer Storage Cloudinary (https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-storage-cloudinary) and also the tutorial here: https://dev.to/franciscomendes10866/image-upload-to-cloudinary-with-node-js-523o

Comment: thanks for the answer, i tried wrote some code I will update the question so you can take a look and let me know how can handle the rest

Comment: Does the file upload successfully to Cloudinary in your latest code (Update 1)?

Comment: Nop, it didn't work

Comment: What is the response you get back from Cloudinary? Are there any errors in the response or in your code?

Comment: Well I tried to upload a file but I got an error I don't remember right now, and I just canceled, and I am looking for another solution.

Comment: You could try using Multer Storage Cloudinary that I mentioned or you can upload to Cloudinary directly and delete the temp file after a successful upload. If you provide more information about the error you encountered we can try to debug it.